# Expressing $\sin(\alpha)$ in terms of $\cos$, and $\cos \alpha$ in terms of $\sin$

Tags: trigonometry

When we express $\sin$ to $\cos$ or from $\cos$ to $\sin$:

why do we want to subtract the angle ($\alpha$) from ($\pi/2$)???

Comment: i know that the angle btw sin and cos is (pie/2) ,but why we need to subtract ??!!!!

Comment: are you asking why  $\cos x=\sin(\frac \pi2-x)$?

Comment: There are no such hard and fast rules. It depends upon the identity or theorem one is trying to prove, or the expression one is trying to simplify. Knowing when to change $sin$ into $cos$ or vice versa, only comes from intuition and experience which can be built by solving a large variety of problems. Solving a lot of problems will make your brain better at recognizing patterns and you will thus develop a "feel" for when to, what to and why to transform. Slowly you will start realizing the usefulness of transformations without actually performing them

Comment: Mmmm... Pie....

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the question in my first comment. I think the OP wanted to know when to transform.

Comment: Yes i'am asking about this rule

Comment: Plz i need help

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: @ZahraaHajHassan What do you mean when you say that the angle between $sin$ and $cos$ is $\pi/2$???

Comment: I mean in the trigonomertic circle the cos is on the x-axis and the sin is on the y-axis and the angle btw these two axis is pie/2

Comment: "cosine" is short for "complementary sine". The cosine of an (acute) angle is, *by definition*, "the sine of the complementary angle".

Comment: All trig identities that you need to answer your question can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Answer (score 0):

Because $\sin(x)=\cos(\pi/2-x)$.

I really don't know what to say beyond this.

Perhaps looking at the angles in a right triangle might give you some insight.

Comment: I need the reason the main reason

Comment: @ZahraaHajHassan Are you asking why $\cos x=\sin(\frac \pi2-x)$???

Comment: Yes,what about this change

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this answers the question, but I've decided to have a go at it anyway.

[image]

Let us consider the $rt. \angle d$ $\Delta$ in the figure above.
Here by definition,
$$\sin\Theta = \frac{o}{h}$$ 
$$ \cos\Theta = \frac{a}{h} $$

Now, clearly the $3^{rd} \angle$ of the $\Delta$ is $\frac{\pi}{2} - \Theta$. 
If we now take into consideration the $T - Ratios$ of $\frac{\pi}{2} - \Theta$, we get,
$$ \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \Theta) = \frac{a}{h} $$
$$ \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - \Theta) = \frac{o}{h} $$

$\therefore$ by comparing the values of $ \sin\Theta$, $\cos\theta$, $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \Theta)$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - \Theta) $, we get,
$$ \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \Theta) = \cos\Theta $$
$$ \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} - \Theta) = \sin\Theta $$

Comment: Any way thank you very much this a good proof